# Merge Objects under the same ID and display in HTML Table in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, object

UPDATE: I should have asked in a better way. My bad. but I struggle to find a way to display it inside a table. I did use reduce() method for this which i got the result by looking at the console log

I am actually stuck on something. As the title above tells you. I need helps on how to get the result for this.

Below is the code

```
let arr = [{
  reference: "A2",
  sendTo: "USA",
  item: "sticker",
  sku: 0921380,
  quantity: 1
},
{
  reference: "A2",
  sendTo: "USA",
  item: "toy",
  sku: 0921381,
  quantity: 2
}, {
  reference: "A2",
  item: "pencil",
  sku: 0921382,
  quantity: 2
},
 {
  reference: "A3",
  item: "sticker",
  sendTo: "USA",
  sku: 0921380,
  quantity: 2
}]

console.log(Array)
```

Javascript I use for this issue (credits to people here for this too):

```
let newArr = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   if(acc.some(obj => obj.reference === curr.reference)) {
       acc.forEach(obj => {
          if(obj.reference === curr.reference) {
          obj.sku = obj.sku + ", " + curr.sku
          obj.quantity = obj.quantity + ", " + curr.quantity
       }
     });
    } else {
        acc.push(curr)
      }
      return acc
    }, [])
```

Result after merging:

```
reference: A2
sendTo: USA
item: sticker, toy, pencil
sku: 0921380, 0921381, 0921382
quantity: 1, 2 ,2

reference: A3
item: sticker
sendTo: USA
sku: 0921380
quantity: 2
```

However, I need to make it appear inside a HTML Table as below:

```
| reference | sendTo | item    | sku      | quantity |
|----------------------------------------------------|
| A2          USA      sticker   0921380    1        |
|                      toy       0921381    2        |
|                      pencil    0921382    2        |
|----------------------------------------------------|
| A3          USA      sticker   0921380    2        |
|----------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: What exactly is the table structure you want: Each address spec in a single cell of a single row or a layout for an adress with labels in the first column and a variable number of columns depending on the number of items keyed with a givene `reference` value, or something different?

Comment: @collapsar I have updated my question on how it looks like

Comment: I have tried reduce() method actually. But then I'm actually stuck on how to display it inside the table. I struggle with that part.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `reduce()` for that.

```js
let arr = [{
  reference: "A0002",
  sendTo: "USA",
  item: "sticker",
  sku: 0921380,
  quantity: 1
},
{
  reference: "A0002",
  sendTo: "USA",
  item: "toy",
  sku: 0921381,
  quantity: 2
}, {
  reference: "A0002",
  item: "pencil",
  sku: 0921382,
  quantity: 2
},
 {
  reference: "A0003",
  item: "sticker",
  sendTo: "USA",
  sku: 0921380,
  quantity: 2
}];

let result = arr.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
     if (exists = previousValue.find(i => i.reference === currentValue.reference)) {
         exists.item += ', ' + currentValue.item;
         exists.sku += ', ' + currentValue.sku;
         exists.quantity += ', ' + currentValue.quantity;
     } else {
         previousValue.push(currentValue);
     }
     return previousValue;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey @sergej thank you for this! My mistake for not clearly state my actual intention for this issue. Issue here is idk how to display on HTML Table. but this is actually helpful as I do see improvement i could make from reduce method i have used

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the elements are already sorted:

```js
const data = [{
  reference: "A0002",
  sendTo: "USA",
  item: "sticker",
  sku: 0921380,
  quantity: 1
},
{
  reference: "A0002",
  sendTo: "USA",
  item: "toy",
  sku: 0921381,
  quantity: 2
}, {
  reference: "A0002",
  item: "pencil",
  sku: 0921382,
  quantity: 2
},
 {
  reference: "A0003",
  item: "sticker",
  sendTo: "USA",
  sku: 0921380,
  quantity: 2
}]

const table = document.getElementById('myTable')
let sameCount = 0
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const row = table.insertRow()
    let cell
    if (sameCount == 0) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < data.length && data[j].reference == data[i].reference; j++)
            sameCount++
        cell = row.insertCell()
        cell.innerHTML = data[i].reference
        cell.setAttribute('rowspan', sameCount + 1)
        cell = row.insertCell()
        cell.innerHTML = data[i].sendTo
        cell.setAttribute('rowspan', sameCount + 1)
    } else {
        sameCount--
    }
    cell = row.insertCell()
    cell.innerHTML = data[i].item
    cell = row.insertCell()
    cell.innerHTML = data[i].sku
    cell = row.insertCell()
    cell.innerHTML = data[i].quantity
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>reference</th>
        <th>sendTo</th>
        <th>item</th>
        <th>sku</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Outline**

You actually do not need the aggregation in order to create the output. Instead, order the data array by the grouping properties ( `reference`, `sendTo` ) and iterate through the result, suppressing output of the group  columns while their (tuple) value does not change.

**Implementation**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SO _: Pivot table gen</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            td, th {
                padding: 0.5em;
                border-left: solid 1px black;
                border-right: solid 1px black;
            }
            td.newGroup, th {
                border-top: solid 1px black;
            }
            tr:last-of-type > td, tr:last-of-type > th {
                border-bottom: solid 1px black;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let arr = [{
              reference: "A0002",
              sendTo: "USA",
              item: "sticker",
              sku: 0921380,
              quantity: 1
            },
            {
              reference: "A0002",
              sendTo: "USA",
              item: "toy",
              sku: 0921381,
              quantity: 2
            }, {
              reference: "A0002",
              sendTo: "USA",
              item: "pencil",
              sku: 0921382,
              quantity: 2
            },
             {
              reference: "A0003",
              item: "sticker",
              sendTo: "USA",
              sku: 0921380,
              quantity: 2
            }];
            
            // in-situ sorting
            arr.sort ( (a, b) => {
                let n_cmp
                  ;
                  
                n_cmp =
                    (a.reference === b.reference)
                        ? Math.sign(a.sku - b.sku)
                        : a.reference.localeCompare(b.reference)
                ;
                return n_cmp;
            });

            
            let orderedColumns = [
                'reference'
              , 'sendTo'
              , 'item'
              , 'sku'
              , 'quantity'
            ];
                            
            console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
            - 'orderedColumns' are the ... well :)
            - 'as_lastKeys' is the array of the currently active grouping key
            - 'b_sameKey' flags for each record that the grouping key has not changed.
            
            - CSS class 'newGroup' identifies the start of a new group and allows for CSS markup to visualize the grouping.
              Note that for convenience the same class is used for non-grouping columns.
              
            - The elements are generated on the fly by scripts.
              The alternative is to use the DOM API to add html elements with attributes.
              The control flow basically is the same, see maraca's answer for details (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72713958)
        -->
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <script>orderedColumns.forEach ( ps_key => { document.write(`<th>${ps_key}</th>`); } );</script>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <script>
                    let as_lastKeys = ['', ''];
                    
                    arr.forEach ( po_record => {
                        let b_sameKey = as_lastKeys.every ( (ps_value, pn_idxKey) => { return ps_value === po_record[orderedColumns[pn_idxKey]]; })
                          ;

                        document.write('<tr>');
                        orderedColumns.forEach ( (ps_key, pn_idxColumn) => {
                            if (pn_idxColumn < as_lastKeys.length) { // Key columns (text not repeated in table output)
                                if (b_sameKey) {
                                    document.write(`<td>&nbsp;</td>`);
                                } else {
                                    as_lastKeys[pn_idxColumn] = po_record[ps_key];
                                    document.write(`<td class="newGroup">${po_record[ps_key]}</td>`);
                                }
                            } else {
                                document.write(`<td class="newGroup">${po_record[ps_key]}</td>`);
                            }
                        });
                        document.write('</tr>');
                    });
                </script>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```